# Как установить библиотеку txlib на Dev-C++

Tags: c++

Как установить библиотеку txlib на Dev-C++?

[Ссылка на документацию библиотеки](http://storage.ded32.net.ru/Lib/TX/TXUpdate/Doc/HTML.ru/index.htm)

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, в чём затруднения с установкой? Какие-то ошибки возникли или неясно где взять код, или вообще непонятно как подключаются библиотеки?

Comment: Кстати, библиотека в один файл на 8499 строк это не то чтобы совсем плохо, но как-то подозрительно. Я бы не стал брать пример и обучаться на такой библиотеке.